# Decode multidimensional json arrays using php

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have the following structure from a json:

```
[46] => stdClass Object
    (
        [task] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => b3:1130806504
                [name] => Prezentare Logos
                [type] => task
                [status] => closed
                [iteration] => Creatie si strategie
                [number] => 
                [dueAt] => 
            )

        [project] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => b3:7700161
                [name] => F.36.35.23.5 Ibalact/Mirdatod
                [workspace] => G7
            )

        [time] => stdClass Object
            (
                [total] => 10800
                [users] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [54928] => 10800
                    )

            )

        [estimate] => 
    )

[47] => stdClass Object
    (
        [task] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => b3:1131005900
                [name] => Declinari KV
                [type] => task
                [status] => open
                [iteration] => Creatie
                [number] => 
                [dueAt] => 
            )

        [project] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => b3:8035237
                [name] => F.52.49.27.4 Single Serve
                [workspace] => G7
            )

        [time] => stdClass Object
            (
                [total] => 28800
                [users] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [57889] => 28800
                    )

            )

        [estimate] => 
    )
```

How can I echo the name for each project and the time for each user:Ex: [57889] => 28800?
This is what I tried so far:

```
$decoded = json_decode($result,true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($decoded);

//echo $decoded[0]->name;

foreach($decoded as $ar){

    foreach($ar->project as $users){

   echo $users;
   echo "<br>";

    }
}
```

This gives me the following:

```
 [id] => b3:7700161
 [name] => F.36.35.23.5 Ibalact/Mirdatod
 [workspace] => G7
```

How can I echo only the name for each project? I made an extra foreach, I even made the following reference: echo $users->name but it shows nothing. I am missing something but I can't figure it out what. Any help.

Comment: To start you should provide the 2nd argument to `json_decode()`. Change you line to `$decoded = json_decode($result,true);` and you will get an array instead of a stdObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
foreach($arr as $ar){
    foreach($ar->users as $users){
        echo $ar->name. ' is '.$users;
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives nothing.

Comment: var_export the array and post it in the question

Comment: it's working, I had set the second argument to true: json_decode($result,true); my bad. After removing true, all works.Thanks for the solution.

Comment: the code above gives me the following: [id] => b3:8035237
                    [name] => F.52.49.27.4 Single Serve
                    [workspace] => G7  Question: I made another foreach in this 2 foreach to get the name of the project but it desn't seem to work, like this: foreach($decoded as $ar){
    
    foreach($ar->project as $users){
     
      foreach($users->name as $bla){
        
        echo $bla;
        
   
    }   
        
   
    }
} but it shows nothing..any idea?

Comment: have you edited your question? . I gave the answered for your previous question

Comment: Yes..but I can't access the last parameter of stdClass Object project..I wrote in above comm what I tried and nothing..